# php convert birthday value to age before json output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I was working on my website and stuck there. My current code is here:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,name,birthday FROM users");

$data=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $data[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

What I trying is before echoing json data I need to modify birthday value  in the array to age using a  function.

In my database birthday format is (1987-09-25)
And I want to convert it to age format(24) before json output.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Search Google for ["php get age from dob"](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=php%20get%20age%20from%20dob&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=a110711d8550a676&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a110711d8550a676&biw=1680&bih=865&ion=1)...there are many, many solutions out there.

Comment: cavin, I already have function for "php get age from dob"

Comment: *I didnt tried anything yet* is usually not a great response. `:)`

Comment: Jared was feeling same when typing that but was stucked and not sure how to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like this.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 $row['age'] = yourFunction( $row['birthday'] );  
 $data[]=$row;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the age automatically within the query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,name,birthday (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthday)) as age FROM users");
```

Comment: Not correct. Infact your query will no take into account the difference of days or months.

Comment: Not sure if it is correct however I will need more things to add later like online status (converting time stamp to online status using function) etc... to scale application it will not be appropriate idea.. Anyways Thanks a lot to answer my question.